# Cannot perform right flow for element found or not found in Cypress

Tags: javascript, automation, automated-tests, cypress, ui-automation

I'm encountering an issue with a Cypress custom command. The command is designed to check for the visibility of certain elements based on the result of another element. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('checkEstablishments', () => {
  accessManagement.getEstablishmentResult().then(($result) => {
    if ($result.length >= 1) {
      accessManagement.getEstablishments()
        .should('be.visible', { timeout: 15000 });
    } else {
      accessManagement.getEstablishmentNotFoundMsg()
        .should('exist')
        .should('be.visible')
        .and('contain.text', 'No establishment found');
    }
  });
});
```

When running this command, I encounter the following error in the Cypress console:

```
if ($result.length >= 1) {
  accessManagement.getEstablishments()
    .should('be.visible');
              ^
} else {
  accessManagement.getEstablishmentNotFoundMsg()
  .should('exist')
```

It seems like there is an issue with using .should('be.visible') after the accessManagement.getEstablishments() call. I'm not sure why this is happening. Can someone please help me understand and resolve this issue?

Comment: Two things missing from the question - what is inside `accessManagement.getEstablishments()` and what is the error?

Comment: @Orla inside the accessManagement.getEstablishments() there are some selectors: //  
getEstablishments(){
    //     return cy.get('.MuiButtonBase-root.MuiButton-root.MuiButton-text.MuiButton-textPrimary.MuiButton-sizeMedium.MuiButton-textSizeMedium.MuiButton-root.MuiButton-text.MuiButton-textPrimary.MuiButton-sizeMedium.MuiButton-textSizeMedium.css-w8tly3-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiButton-root')
    // }
  I am trying to search first for this element, if not found then I should see the   accessManagement.getEstablishmentNotFoundMsg() element. It is looking only for getEstablishments element.